# Cyclic hexagon gives equilateral triangle

Tags: geometry, complex-numbers, vectors, euclidean-geometry, circles

> Suppose that $ABCDEF$ is a cyclic hexagon and the radius of a circumcircle is $r$. Suppose further that $|AB|=|CD|=|EF|=r$. Let the midpoints of $BC, DE$ and $FA$ be $M_1$, $M_2$ and $M_3$ respectively. Is the triangle $M_1M_2M_3$ necessary equilateral?

I tried to use the law of cosines to prove that, but it was hard to prove that those system of equations has a solution only is three variable are equal. I also tried to rotate the triangle but could not found anything useful. I thing it has something to do with the fact that the equal length of hexagon sides is used to perform angle equalities.

Comment: Experiments with geogebra show that the result is correct.

Comment: This statement can be proved synthetically by reducing the problem to Napoleon's theorem.

Comment: @Jaakko Seppälä , This can be easily derived by twisting the Equilateral triangle of a known theorem known as ***Asymmetrical propeller theorem on Equilateral triangle***

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer is YES.

WOLOG, consider the case $r = 1$, the circumcenter is located at origin and the vertices are arranged in counterclockwise manner along the circumcircle.

Identify the euclidean plane $\mathbb{R}^2$ with the complex plane $\mathbb{C}$. We will abuse the notation and use same symbol to denote a point in the euclidean plane and the corresponding number in complex plane.

Let $\omega = e^{i\pi/3}$ be the primitive root of unity with order $6$.

Since $|AB| = |CD| = |EF| = r = 1$ and $A, \cdots, F$ are arranged counterclockwisely along the circumcircle, we have

$$
\begin{cases}
B = \omega A,\\
D = \omega C,\\
F = \omega E\\
\end{cases}
\implies 
\begin{cases}
M_1 = \frac12(B+C) = \frac12( \omega A + C)\\
M_2 = \frac12(D+E) = \frac12( \omega C + E)\\
M_3 = \frac12(F+A) = \frac12( \omega E + A)
\end{cases}
$$
Notice following three complex numbers are multiple of each other upto some powers of $\omega^2$.

$$\begin{align}
M_2 - M_1 &= \frac12 ((\omega - 1) C + E - \omega A)
= \frac12 ( E + \omega^2 C + \omega^4 A),\\
M_3 - M_2 &= \frac12((\omega - 1) E + A - \omega C)
= \frac12 ( A + \omega^2 E + \omega^4 C) = \omega^2 (M_2 - M_1)\\
M_1 - M_3 &= \frac12((\omega - 1) A + C  - \omega E)
= \frac12 ( C + \omega^2 A + \omega^4 E ) = \omega^2 (M_3 - M_2)
\end{align}
$$

Translate these relations back to Euclidean plane.

We can obtain the line segment $M_2M_3$ from $M_1M_2$ by a counterclockwise rotation of $120^\circ$ followed by a translation to move $M_1$ into $M_2$. Similarly, we can obtain the line segment $M_3M_1$ from $M_2M_3$ by a counterclockwise rotation of $120^\circ$ followed by a translation to move $M_2$ into $M_3$.

As a result, $\triangle M_1M_2M_3$ is an equilateral triangle.

Answer (score 3):

It's true because

$$R_{60^{\circ}}\left(\vec{M_3M_2}\right)=R_{60^{\circ}}\left(\frac{1}{2}\left(\vec{AD}+\vec{FE}\right)\right)=$$
$$=R_{60^{\circ}}\left(\frac{1}{2}\left(\vec{AO}+\vec{OD}+\vec{FE}\right)\right)=$$
$$=\frac{1}{2}\left(\vec{AB}+\vec{OC}+\vec{FO}\right)=$$
$$=\frac{1}{2}\left(\vec{AB}+\vec{FC}\right)=\vec{M_3M_1}.$$
Done!

Comment: What do you mean? In that case the whole figure shrinks to a single point.

Comment: But $A\to C$ and $C\to E$ if $r\to 0+$ so the triangle $ACE$ is a point. Could you elaborate the solution?

Comment: I still don't understand. all the points $A,B,C,D,E,F$ are on the circumcircle of a circle with radius $r$. If $r\to 0+$ then $X\to A$ for every $X\in \{B,C,D,E,F,M_1,M_2,M_3\}$. So $\triangle ACE$ is just a point.

Comment: @user2219896 Is something not clear?

Comment: I haven't seen the $R_{60^\circ}$ before. Is it $60^\circ$ rotation? Around what point? It would be nice to learn the definition of the $R$ so I could learn to use it properly.

Comment: @user2219896 If we use a rotation of  the vector then the result does not depend on the point around which it rotates and from here we can rotate every vector around the tail of the vector.

Answer (score 0):

Let $N_1, N_2, N_3$ be the midpoints of segments $EF, AB, CD$ respectively and let $O$ be the center of the circle. The three triangles $ABO, CDO, EFO$ are equilateral so if you perform $60^{\circ}$ rotation around $O$, the points $A, C, E$ are mapped to $B, D, F$ respectively, so triangle $ACE$ is mapped to triangle $BDF$ which means that segments $AC, CE, EA$ are mapped to segments $BD, DF, FB$ respectively. Thus, $|AC| = |BD|$ and the angle between them is $60^{\circ}$, $|CE| = |DF|$ and the angle between them is $60^{\circ}$,  $|EA| = |FB|$ and the angle between them is $60^{\circ}$.

Now, the segment $N_2M_1$ is a mid-segment of triangle $ABC$, so $N_2M_1 \, || \, AC$ and $|N_2M_1| = \frac{1}{2}|AC|$. Furthermore, segment $M_1N_3$ is a mid-segment of triangle $BCD$, so $M_1N_3 \, || \, BD$ and $|M_1N_3| = \frac{1}{2}|ND|$. Therefore, $\angle \, N_2M_1N_3 = 120^{\circ}$ and $|N_2M_1| = |M_1N_3|$.  Analogously,  $\angle \, N_3M_2N_1 = 120^{\circ}$ and $|N_3M_2| = |M_2N_1|$ as well as  $\angle \, N_2M_1N_3 = 120^{\circ}$ and $|N_2M_1| = |M_1N_3|$. These observations show that if one constructs the three external equilateral triangles on the three sides of the triangle $N_2N_3N_1$ then the points $M_1, M_2, M_3$ are the centroids of the said three equilateral triangles. Since this is the configuration of Napoleon's Theorem, it follows immediately that triangle $M_1M_2M_3$ is equilateral.